# Can I set a specific storage for one of my web app on my EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, web-hosting

Hope you're well

Now I have a running EC2 instance and I already host some web apps, my instance's storage is 20 GB, so I'm asking is it possible that I can assign a fixed storage for one of these running apps?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want each running application to have their own EBS Volume? Do you want to increase the instance's storage with each new web application? What exactly are you trying to accomplish, more details about that would be helpful.

Comment: @strongjz , yeah I wanna attach a specific EBS to single web app

Comment: You can add an EBS volume and then inside the OS you can mount it to whatever filesystem and path you want for that web app.

Comment: @strongjz but the web apps should be inside `/var/www/html` path? so I might made a soft link `ln -s` for them?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options when choosing the EBS storage for an instance.

1. EBS optimized
2. IOPS
3. Instance Type
4. Raiding volumes

But to change it the instance type you'll need to create a snapshot and restore a volume from the [snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-restoring-volume.html) . You'll also want to look into changing the instance type that supports EBS optimized, this creates a dedicated network channel for EBS communication and is not effect by the network traffic of the instance.

You can also modify the EBS volume in the console,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/console-modify.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSPerformance.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSOptimized.html

Comment: So the EBS is assigned for the whole instance at first, what if I wanna assign a specific size to a single web app that running on the instance?

Comment: You can attach another volume for that specific web application.

Comment: Really, how come?

Comment: I am confused by your question. I thought that is what you wanted, specific volumes for each web application.

Comment: What confusing you?

Answer (score 0):

When you created the instance, you probably allocated space, which automatically creates an Elastic Block Storage volume and attaches it to your EC2 instance.

You can create additional volumes and attach (and then map) them to your EC2 instance. Or, you can take a snapshot, and create a new volume with a different size and switch the attached volumes.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/block-device-mapping-concepts.html

**Edit:**
Since you have multiple virtual host on the same instance, you can create additional volumes and map them in your instance. Then you can set the virtual host directories to those newly mapped folders. However, the specifics of both of those are beyond the scope of this question.

So TL;DR; yes, it is possible.

Comment: But this is assigned to a single instance. I wanna assign a specific storage for **single web app** on my running instance.

Comment: So you have multiple virtual hosts on the same instance? You can map multiple volumes to the same EC2 instance (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/add-instance-store-volumes.html)

Comment: I have multiple web apps running on the instance, yeah

Answer (score 0):

Here are the exact steps to do, assuming you are on centos based system.

**Reference**:
 [Making an Amazon EBS Volume Available for Use](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html)
 [What happens when you 'mount over' an existing folder with contents?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198542/what-happens-when-you-mount-over-an-existing-folder-with-contents)

```
# EBS device name
ebs_location=/dev/xvdb
# Lets say you application is in /etc/apps/
mount_folder=/etc/apps
temp_mount_folder="/mnt/temp-mount"

#Configure EBS volume and Create a temp mount point
mkfs -t ext4 $ebs_location
mkdir ${temp_mount_folder}
mount ${ebs_location} ${temp_mount_folder}
#Copy all the files from /etc/apps to the temp location
cp -ax ${mount_folder}/* ${temp_mount_folder}

#Umount the temp location
umount "${ebs_location}"
#rename the /etc/apps/ to /etc/apps.old
mv "${mount_folder}" "${mount_folder}.old"
mkdir "${mount_folder}"

#update fstab file to mount EBS on system startup
echo "UUID=${disk_uuid} ${mount_folder} ext4 defaults,relatime,nofail 0 0" >> /etc/fstab

#mount the EBS volume on /etc/apps
mount ${ebs_location} ${mount_folder}
rm -r ${temp_mount_folder}
```

Comment: So this make one of my running web app having it's own EBS volume?

Comment: Thank you for your reply